# Graphics always rendered twice with SimpleFrontEnd example?

Tags: graphics, java

I am looking at the Java `SimpleFrontEnd` example provided by *Mathematica*. Everything goes well except it always renders graphics twice.

[image]

Can anyone help me with this?

BTW: I am using version 9 under ubuntu 14.04 (32 bit).

Comment: Where, exactly, is that example in the Documentation Center?

Comment: Hi @murray, it's under:/usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/9.0/SystemFiles/Links/JLink/Examples/Part2

Comment: I asked where it is in the Documentation Center. If it's an example, I would presume it's accessible from there.

Comment: @murray, It's not in the Documentation Center, you could access it from installation folder I pasted.